# Jquery multiple IF statements not working correctly, possible priority issue?

Tags: jquery

I have this script that checks 2 drop down fields upon submissions and sends the user to 1 of 3 landing pages based on their selection. If none of these fields are matched, they go to a 3rd default landing page not listed here. The problem is, if they choose the role "Realtor / Real Estate Team Leader / Broker" I want them to go to landingpage-1 regardless of the loan selected. But if they select loans of "< 10" or "10 - 24", they go to landingpage-2. I tried adding the first 2 if statements for those specific cases, but it doesnt' work. Any ideas on how to have the selection of the role "Realtor / Real Estate Team Leader / Broker" take priority over any of the loan selection options, and send them to landingpage-1?

Thank you!

```js
<script>
  lp.jQuery(function($) {
    $('#form-1').live('change',function(){
        var selectedLoan = $('#loan').val();
        var selectedRole = $('#role').val();
      
       if(selectedLoan == "< 10" && selectedRole == "Realtor / Real Estate Team Leader / Broker"){
          window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData = "https://mycompany.com/landingpage-1/";
  }
        if(selectedLoan == "10 - 24" && selectedRole == "Realtor / Real Estate Team Leader / Broker"){
          window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData = "https://mycompany.com/landingpage-1/";
  }
        if(selectedRole == "Realtor / Real Estate Team Leader / Broker"){
          window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData = "https://mycompany.com/landingpage-1/";
        }
        if(selectedLoan == "< 10"){
          window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData = "https://mycompany.com/landingpage-2/";
        }
        if(selectedLoan == "10 - 24"){
          window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData = "https://mycompany.com/landingpage-2/";
        }
        if(selectedRole == "Loan Officer / Originator"){
          window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData = "https://mycompany.com/landingpage-2/";
        }
        if(selectedRole == "Branch Manager"){
          window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData = "https://mycompany.com/landingpage-2/";
        }
        if(selectedRole == "Individual Contributor - Sales"){
          window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData = "https://mycompany.com/landingpage-2/";
        }
        if(selectedRole == "Individual Contributor - Other"){
          window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData = "https://mycompany.com/landingpage-2/";
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `$('..').val()` on a select input does not return you the actual option text, but the option inline value attribute, to get the text you need use `$("#myselect option:selected").text();`

Comment: Thanks, I probably should have noted, the 2 fields are drop downs and the inline values exactly match the selected inputs in the script. It is working for all cases, except when selected role is "Realtor / Real Estate Team Leader / Broker" and selected loan is either "< 10" or "10 - 24". So the loan selection appears to be overriding the Realtor role selection.